# Prolog sandwich predicate

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

I need to make a predicate `sandwich(L)` which is true if it has the same elements at the beginning and end of the list, like this:

```
sandwich([a,a,b,c,d,a,a]).
```

Could you please help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: Take a lokk at `append`, it is very useful to understand how it works ! Does sandwich([a,b,a]) succeed ?

Comment: I did, but I still couldn't do it.

Comment: Well, append([a,b,c], [a], L) gives L = [a,b,c,a] and to get the first element of a list L, you can write L = [H |  _] ! Hope this help.

Comment: To write in Prolog, you have to think about the problem logically. If a list `L` has the same element at both ends, can you think of what lists `A` and `B` might look like if `append(A, B, L)` is true? And note that a list can be written as `[H|T]` where `H` is the first element and `T` is the rest (tail) of the list. Also a list of one element looks like `[X]`.

Comment: Problem is I only have this information: that if I ask sandwich([a,a,b,c,d,a,a]) prolog will answer "yes". I've done other predicates with append, but I'm having troubles defining this one!

Comment: What are the important elements ? the first and the last. You can ignore the rest. With Prolog, to ignore something you can write _, as I wrote with L = [H | _]. So you need to find a list which begins with an atom A, when you append this list with the list [A] you get a list wich starts and ends with the same atom.

Comment: Yep, the only information you have is the problem you were given. That's a pretty standard situation for a homework assignment. ;) You've got two strong clues to work with here and have only spent a couple of minutes thinking about it so far. So give it some further thought. You can also do it without append if you think through the rules. One rule (the easy one) is that a list with two elements the same is a sandwich, so `sandwich([X,X]).` is true. Then you have to think recursively: *if a list that looks like `[X,_|T]` is a sandwich, then the list ___ is a sandwich* and write that in Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite clear what a "sandwich" should be, but this is probably the purpose of your assignment. After all, most requirements are never that clearcut. Using a DCG seems to be a good idea. It might be

```
sandwich(X) :-
   phrase(sandwich).

sandwich --> [X], ..., [X].

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

or

```
sandwich --> [X,X], ... , [X,X].
```

or maybe both. And is `[X]` a sandwich, too?

Comment: I don't think `[X]` is a sandwich. It would be like one slice of bread. So I think your first solution is correct. But then again, using that metaphor, `[X,X]` would be like two slices of bread with nothing in between. So maybe that's not really a sandwich either? If it is, then `[X]` would be an "open face sandwich. :)